# Netstat shows two sshd's listening, but only one pid

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, netstat, linode

On my Linode sudo netstat -tulp gives me:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address   State    PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 *:ssh            *:*               LISTEN   2030/sshd           
tcp        0      0 *:http           *:*               LISTEN   2178/httpd          
tcp        0      0 *:ssh            *:*               LISTEN   2030/sshd           
udp        0      0 *:bootpc         *:*                        1937/dhclient
```

Why is sshd on there twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of those is listening for IPv4 connections, one is listening for IPv6 connections:

```
michael:~> netstat -tl |grep ssh
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      
michael:~> netstat -tln |grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```